# Files not showing on a LUKS Encrypted Partition shared by two distros

Tags: encryption, permissions, linux-mint, manjaro, luks

I have had a good internet search for this problem, and can find nothing at all.
I have just installed Manjaro and Linux Mint on a friend's Laptop.
I am not new to Linux, used Gentoo, Arch, Ubuntu, CentoOS for a good 20 years or more, and he is an experienced Ubuntu & Mint man.
He has an encrypted partition which is mounted on a folder in his Home Folder called **rob_docs** with Ownership set to rob:rob
The user rob as an UID of 1000 on each Distro.
When he saves files to rob_docs on Manjaro they are not seen in Mint and vice-versa.
I cannot see any reason for this. The /dev/mapper/rob_docs is the same in each distro as is the luks keyfile in /root/
Here are the relevant permissions from each Distro:
**Manjaro**

```
$ ls -l ~/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 1 rob rob    0 Apr  7 13:08 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 1 rob rob    0 Apr  7 13:08 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 1 rob rob    0 Apr  7 13:08 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 1 rob rob    0 Apr  7 13:08 Music
drwxr-xr-x 1 rob rob    0 Apr  7 13:08 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 1 rob rob    0 Apr  7 13:08 Public
drwxr-xr-x 5 rob rob 4096 Apr  8 11:38 rob_docs
drwxr-xr-x 1 rob rob    0 Apr  7 13:08 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 1 rob rob    0 Apr  7 13:08 Videos

$ ls -l ~/rob_docs
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 2 rob rob  4096 Apr  7 17:12 firefox
-rw-r--r-- 1 rob rob 10961 Apr  8 11:38 grub-info-manjaro.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 rob rob  4096 Apr  7 17:21 info
drwx------ 2 rob rob 16384 Apr  4 13:21 lost+found
```

**Mint**

```
$ ls -l ~/
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 2 rob rob 4096 Apr  5 19:49 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 rob rob 4096 Apr  5 19:49 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 3 rob rob 4096 Apr  7 12:14 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 2 rob rob 4096 Apr  5 19:49 Music
drwxr-xr-x 2 rob rob 4096 Apr  5 19:49 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 rob rob 4096 Apr  5 19:49 Public
drwxrwxr-x 6 rob rob 4096 Apr  8 11:00 rob_docs
drwxrwxr-x 3 rob rob 4096 Apr  7 13:32 ROB-FG
drwxr-xr-x 2 rob rob 4096 Apr  5 19:49 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 2 rob rob 4096 Apr  5 19:49 Videos

$ ls -l ~/rob_docs
total 52
-rw-rw-r--  1 rob rob     0 Apr  6 09:31 EmptyFile.txt
drwxrwxr-x  3 rob rob  4096 Apr  7 18:39 firefox
-rw-rw-r--  1 rob rob  9047 Apr  8 11:00 grub-info.txt
drwxr-xr-x 26 rob rob 12288 Mar 29 15:24 TEFL_course
drwxrwxr-x  2 rob rob  4096 Apr  7 18:36 test_folder
drwxr-xr-x  3 rob rob  4096 Apr  8 10:46 video_recordings
```

As you can see it is as if they are two different partitions, but they are not. The UUID to mount /dev/mapper/rob_docs is identical in each /etc/fstab file.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by reinstalling Mint without the boot option - From the cmmmand line in the Live DVD:-

ubiquity -b

Because Manjaro and another Linux Distro only use one EFI Partition so Manjaro is used to update grub for the boot menu.
Then recreated the LUKS Partition and all was well, both distros would write and read from the LUKS Partiton